# Retrieving comments number (facebook) in WordPress

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress

I have both default WordPress and Facebook comments enabled on my WordPress blog.

Of course, my theme only shows comment number of WordPress comments.

What I need is a way to retrieve the number of comments from Facebook comments box on every post and then add it to the comments number of WordPress comments.

I can not use

```
<fb:comments-count href=http://example.com/></fb:comments-count>
```

because it uses javascript.
I am not proficient in php so any help would be great.
I know I can use graph api, but don't know how to get comments number and add it to WordPress count.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about the wordpress part of things, but you can use the [facebook FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql) to get the number of comments using the [link_stat table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/):

```
SELECT commentsbox_count
FROM link_stat
WHERE url="http://example.com"
```

Be sure that the url you use for the query matches **exactly** to the url used in the comments plugin.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Could you please be more specific, as I am noob in php and would not want to break the blog down.
I tried with this code:

    <?php SELECT commentsbox_count FROM link_stat WHERE url="<?php $permalink = get_permalink( $id ); ?>" ?>

but I get mistake.

Comment: Check out the [PHP SDK for facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) to learn how to do that, especially the [api method](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/). I'm not a php programmer and not very good with wordpress so I can't help you there.

Answer (score 0):

or you can use this

```
<fb:comments-count href=http://example.com/></fb:comments-count>
```

And wrap a 'span' around it

or this iframe version

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?href=example.com&permalink=1" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:130px; height:16px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

but you can read more about it on this page - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/